# Import class in same file in Python

Tags: python, import

I'm new to python and I have a file with several classes. In a method in the class "class1" I want to use a method from another class "class2". How do I do the import and how do I call the method from class1? I have tried several different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: +1 for the Little My avatar, anyway.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this, class shouldn't access the other class's methods. It's not like `Car` should be able to call methods of a `Plane`, right?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen what do you mean? Classes access the methods of other classes all the time.

Comment: @Steven I can't think of an example where `Human` would use `Wolf.howl()` method, nor would `Car` use `Plane.fly()`. **Edit:** I probably misunderstood the question, I now feel like he wants to create a `Hammer` object and then have a `Human` object use the hammer to smash something. What I was referring to is that a human wouldn't use the `smash()` method himself, he would use it *through* a hammer object. My bad.

Comment: As many many others have mentioned, you don't need to import class2. However, class2 should be defined before class1 in the file for the Python interpreter to let you use class2 in class1.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to import them, because they are already in the same file.

Instead, do something like this:

```
class1 = Class1() #assigns class1 to your first class
```

Then call a method inside of `Class1` like this:

```
Class2():
    def method2(self):
        class1.method1() #call your method from class2
```

Basically you are taking `Class2()` and pointing it to the instance `class2`, then you are calling a method of that class by doing `class2.method2()`. It's just like calling a function from the current class, but you use instance name in front of it.

Here is an example:

```
class Class1():

    def method1(self):
        print "hello"

class Class2():
    def method2(self)
        class1 = Class1()
        class1.method1()
```

Then, when you call `Class2()` it will print 'hello'.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your file with all the classes is called `myclass.py` with the following:

```
class Class2(object):
    def foo(self):
        return 'cabbage'

class Class1(Class2):
    def bar(self):
        return self.foo()
```

In your main script, you can import the module as usual:

```
import myclass
```

And now you can create an instance of `class1`:

```
myinstance = myclass.Class1()
```

Then you can call the function directly:

```
myinstance.bar()
# Returns 'cabbage'
```

Answer (score 2):

If all of the classes are in the same file, you don't need to import them. They are in the module scope already. Here's an example:

```
class A():
    def print_one(self):
        print "one"

class B():
    def print_two_and_one(self):
        print "two"
        A().print_one()

B().print_two_and_one()
```

Comment: Interesting, what was the reason for downvoting?